# updating to Indy version 10.6.2

Tags: delphi, indy, idhttp

I have not been able to find a place from where I can download the 10.6.2 Indi vesion and upgrade from the older version 1.6.0.4975.

We are using XE4 and Seattle10 and the older IDHTTP component works with Seattle10 but stopped working in XE4.B Stopped working I mean the user receives an "Socket error 10054. Connection was reset by peer" error.

comparing 2 projects; one from XE$ and the other from Seattle10 the only difference is the Delphi IDE version. Indy version# is the same in both IDE's.

So I need to update Indy to the 10.6.2 version and need help finding the download for it.

Thanks.

Comment: "*the user receives an "Socket error 10054. Connection was reset by peer" error*" - what makes you think upgrading Indy will fix that? That error means the remote peer (ie, the web server) is closing the connection in its end while your client is still sending/receiving data to/from it.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Indy's code is in Indy's GitHub repo: https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/

Install instructions are in the repo's wiki: https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/wiki/Updating-Indy

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Before posting my question here I stumbled upon a post https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/317 where it was mentioned that updating might solve some errors. I am not well versed with http and do not know how to start resolving this. I have tried increasing the connection timeout but did not help. With Postman I was able to get the expected result and also by directly pasting the http code in Firefox. Cannot get it to work using Indy in XE4.